# Number of parameters in an LSTM cell

Tags: neural-networks, python, lstm, keras, weights

I am not sure how to calculate my LSTM weights based on this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226593/how-can-calculate-number-of-weights-in-lstm)
and my Keras programing as below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM1(A1, input_shape=(2,B1), return_sequences=True, stateful=False)) 
model.add(LSTM2(A2, return_sequences=True, stateful=False))
model.add(LSTM3(A3, return_sequences=False, stateful=False))
model.add(Dense(B2, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

Is that correct?

```
Input = A1
Output = B2
Hidden Layers = 2
Cells in layer number one = A2
Cells in layer number two = A3
```

Finally:

```
4*ni*(ni−1+ni) for each layer is calculated as below:
X1=4*A1*(A1-1+A1)
X2=4*A2*(A2-1+A2)
X3=4*A3*(A3-1+A3)
X4=4*B2*(B2-1+B2)
Total number of weights = X1+X2+X3+X4
```

All my problem is about understanding the concept of cell in Keras and not in LSTM itself.

Comment: Does your parameter count match what you get from `model.summary()`? If it's different, how?

Answer (score 1):

Your arithmetic won't give you the total number of parameters for several reasons.

- You're subtracting 1 from the parameter count. The notation in the linked post is using a subscript $n_{i-1}$, which is an index, and does not mean $n_i - 1$.
- Your arithmetic is incorrect because you're not using the input and output sizes correctly.
- You're using bias neurons in your LSTM, so you need too add those in as well.

Making these corrections, the number of parameters in the first LSTM layer is `X1=4*A1*(B1+A1)+4*A1`, and the second is `X2=4*A2*(A1+A2)+4*A2`.

Instead of the notation used in the post, I find it easier to understand using this notation instead:
`params = 4 * ((size_of_input + 1) * size_of_output + size_of_output^2)`